# python3/hy - When using hy.eval, imports and globals are not shared

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, python-import, hy

I understand how to use `hy.read_str` and `hy.eval` from python to evaluate an `hy` expression from within python. However, when I use this methodology, imports and globals are not shared between the `hy` and `python` environments. Consider this example:

```
import hy
def hyeval(x=None):
    if x is None:
        return None
    try:
        return hy.eval(hy.read_str(str(x)))
    except Exception as e:
        print('!!! exception: {}'.format(e))
        return None
import datetime  # this is ignored within `hyeval` calls
now = hyeval('((. datetime datetime now))')
print('result: {}'.format(now))
```

This prints ...

```
!!! exception: name 'datetime' is not defined
result: None
```

Even if I do the following, it generates the same exception ...

```
... etc. ...
hyeval('(import datetime)')
now = hyeval('((. datetime datetime now))')
print('result: {}'.format(now))
```

I have to explicitly import `datetime` within the string
passed to my `hyeval` function ...

```
... etc. ...
now = hyeval('((do (import datetime) (. datetime datetime now)))')
print('result: {}'.format(now))
```

This properly prints the following ...

```
result: 2017-09-22 09:41:49.771139
```

If I re-invoke the `((. datetime datetime now))` call via a string, I have to keep repeating the `(import datetime)` call via a `(do ...)` block.

Is there any way when invoking `hy` strings from within python that imports and globals can be remembered between successive calls to `hy.read_str/hy.eval`, or that the python globals and imports can be recognized when invoking strings via `hy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out: if the second argument to `hy.eval` is `globals()`, the python environment's globals and imports are available when performing the `hy` string evaluation ...

```
import hy
def hyeval(x=None, g=None):
    if x is None:
        return None
    try:
        if not g:
            g = globals()
        return hy.eval(hy.read_str(str(x)), g)
    except Exception as e:
        print('!!! exception: {}'.format(e))
        return None
import datetime
now = hyeval('((. datetime datetime now))')
print('result: {}'.format(now))
```

This correctly prints the following ...

```
result: 2017-09-22 10:25:36.752656
```